# Pass MySQL data from one php page to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have media_main.php that is obtaining data from a MySQL database.  One of the pieces of data obtained is "filename" using the mySQL SELECT statement.  On media_main.php, there is a link to open player.php which has a flash MP3 player embedded.  The link to open the new window is as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="return popitup('player.php')" title="Listen">
```

I would like "filename" to be passed from media_main.php to the player.php page.  I think I need to use GET or POST, but am not sure how to since the data isn't coming directly from a form.

Comment: `return popitup('player.php?filename=your_file_name');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by reading `$_GET['file']` on player.php, and setting it on media_main.php.

On `media_main.php` you would use PHP to make the link dynamic:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="return popitup('player.php?file=<?php echo $Data['filename']; ?>')" title="Listen">
```

Which would result in:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="return popitup('player.php?file=dynamic_file.mp3')" title="Listen">
```

Then on player.php, you would echo `$_GET['file']` where you want the file to be included.

Also, be sure to validate all data. To make it safe to display on your website, you can wrap `$_GET['file']` with htmlentities(), so that a user can't use the `$_GET['file']` to display HTML on your site.

Comment: When clicking on the player.php link the MP3 opens in a new tab and start streaming rather than opening in the popitup window?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to pass it on the query string. In other words, the `popitup` function can do this:

```
onclick="popitup('player.php?song=songname.mp3');"
```

Then `player.php` can read the query string and get the song name and start playing it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that there are a couple other pieces of data that I would also like to pass that don't have to do with the filename.

Comment: @Nick: It doesn't have to be just one parameter; you can pass: `player.php?song=songname.mp3&onemore=otherparam&foo=bar` etc.

Comment: When clicking on the player.php link the MP3 opens in a new tab and start streaming rather than opening in the popitup window?

Comment: @Nick: that means you are not constructing the URL properly and instead you are just linking the mp3 file alone. Check how are you generating the link to the player.php window again.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done through passing file name in query string to the called page for ex:

```
 <a href="javascript:;" onclick="return popitup('player.php?file_name=test.mp3')"
   title="Listen">
```

here test.mp3 is an ex: this should be the file name you are getting from database.
and @ the player.php you will get file_name by using $_REQUEST['file_name'];

Comment: The data is passing, however I am unable to show that data on the player.php page.  This is what I have: `code` <p><?php $_REQUEST['file_name']; ?></p>

Comment: Oh my...I was missing echo.  Thanks for your time!!

Comment: **<?php echo $_REQUEST['file_name']; ?>**

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you should never pass to the server the data that already exists there.

So, pass only identifier, and in the player.php do a database request and get the filename.

Comment: This is great information.  If I only pass the identifier, what would be the best way to obtain the data on the player.php page?

Comment: a regular SQL query. just select a filename from songs table where id = passed identifier. Don't forget to sanitize this identifier before placing it into query.